# Twig - Trim exact string only

Tags: twig

I want to trim a string using twig. The documentation for trim is located [here](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/trim.html).

```
{{ 'I like Twig!'|trim('!') }}

{# outputs 'I like Twig' #}
```

The above example trims exclamation marks from the string.

Consider the following:

```
{{ 'ROLE_USER'|trim('ROLE_') }}
```

One would think this would trim `ROLE_` and return `USER`. That's not how it works:

```
{# outputs 'US' #}
```

This is because the letters `E` and `R` are also in `ROLE_`, hence they are also removed.

How can I circumvent this, perhaps with a regular expression, or replacing **only exactly** the string I want?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What about the [replace](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/replace.html) filter?

```
{{ 'ROLE_USER'|replace({'ROLE_': ''}) }}
//outputs
USER
```

Comment: Hah, you're kidding! Docs didn't show this, thanks - easy rep ;)

Comment: True :D But still glad to help ;)